# Error when parsing a recordset in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Got a stupid problem, it seams simple but I just don't get it.
Got a very simple vba code for an excel sheet:

```
Private Sub GET_MDW_DATA()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmdSQLData As ADODB.Command
    Set cmdSQLData = New ADODB.Command

    Dim cnstr As String

    Dim usr
    Set usr = Nothing
    usr = Sheet1.Cells(1, 4).Value

    Dim pwd
    Set pwd = Nothing
    pwd = Sheet1.Cells(2, 4).Value

    Dim odbcname
    Set odbcname = Nothing
    odbcname = Sheet1.Cells(1, 8).Value

    Dim Category As String
    Category = Sheet1.Cells(1, 6).Value

    Dim Store As String
    Store = Sheet1.Cells(2, 6).Value

    cnstr = "Data Source=" & odbcname & "; Database=belccp_msi_d; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=" & usr & "; Password=" & pwd & "; Session Mode=ANSI;"
    cn.Open cnstr

    Set cmdSQLData.ActiveConnection = cn
    Sheet1.Range("A6 : H1000000").Clear

    Query = "SELECT SOMETHING FROM SOME DATABASE"


    cmdSQLData.CommandText = Query
    cmdSQLData.CommandType = adCmdText
    cmdSQLData.CommandTimeout = 0
    Set rs = cmdSQLData.Execute()
    rs.MoveFirst

    x = 6
    Do While (rs.BOF = False or rs.EOF = False)
        p = rs.GetRows(-1)
        Sheet1.Range("A" & x).Value = p(0, 8)
        Sheet1.Range("B" & x).Value = p(1, 8)
        Sheet1.Range("C" & x).Value = p(2, 8)
        Sheet1.Range("D" & x).Value = p(3, 8)
        Sheet1.Range("E" & x).Value = p(4, 8)
        Sheet1.Range("F" & x).Value = p(5, 8)
        Sheet1.Range("G" & x).Value = p(6, 8)
        Sheet1.Range("H" & x).Value = p(7, 8)

        x = x + 1

    Loop

    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cmdSQLData = Nothing
```

If I "print" my select, copy it and execute it in an query, it returns 30 rows from my database, but when I execute it from my excel "code" it only returns 1 row, only one line from the 30 lines.

I have checked it and just before `x=x+1` the `rs.EOF` is `True`. That means either that my record set has only one value (if so why? because my select returns 30 rows) or that I don't parse it correctly. Any hints?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but any reason you use `rs.GetRows(-1)`? Because according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675120(v=vs.85).aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677558(v=vs.85).aspx), that will fetch _ALL_ records at once into your `p` (thus two-dimensional array). Generally `rs(0)`, `rs(1)`, etc., with `rs.MoveNext` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A strange thing that I noticed in your code is that you use the GetRows function in a loop.

`GetRows` loads the recordset into an array.
Either you loop through the array returned by `GetRows`, or you loop through the recordset.   There is no reason why you would do both at the same time.

In case you loop through the recordset, you would have something like:

```
x = 6 'As you prefer
rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF

    Sheet1.Range("A" & x).Value = rs![field_name_1]
    Sheet1.Range("B" & x).Value = rs![field_name_2]
    Sheet1.Range("C" & x).Value = rs![field_name_3]
    Sheet1.Range("D" & x).Value = rs![field_name_4]
    Sheet1.Range("E" & x).Value = rs![field_name_5]
    Sheet1.Range("F" & x).Value = rs![field_name_6]
    Sheet1.Range("G" & x).Value = rs![field_name_7]
    Sheet1.Range("H" & x).Value = rs![field_name_8]

    rs.MoveNext

Loop
```

To check how many records there are in your recordset, use:

```
rs.MoveLast
iRecordCount = rs.RecordCount
```

Comment: when using rs![field_name_1] it gives me some error. Should I use instead of rs![field_name_1] the actual field name as it is from my select?